# Bounty answer provided User help but not accepted. No other answer was provided

Tags: discussion, bounty

I am curious as to the policy or etiquette of the following situation:

Question was posed (with a 50 point bounty).

Only one answer was provided, which went a long way to explain to the user what the issue was and provided workable code to get the questioner, well on their way.

The answer had gotten an up vote and the questioner had acknowledged that he had tried to copy and paste the code that and it didn't work, although the answer had a caveat that they may need to tinker with a specific query to get the desired result.

In the comments, further help was offered but no further assistance was requested. Is it possible that the user simply wants to avoid giving up bounty points?

Comment: `Is it possible that the user simply wants to avoid giving up bounty points?` Nope, once posted the rep is lost, so the person who offered the bounty has zero incentive to not award it

Comment: Ah, Thanks! That clarifies it for me.

Comment: I'm also going to take a wild guess and assume [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42492996/asp-net-core-entity-framework-7-insert-statement-conflicted-with-the-foregign-k) is the inspiration for the hypothetical scenario you are asking about.  Take note that the bounty has **5 days** left to go.  Relax and see what happens.  The OP might award it to you after the bounty ends, someone else might come along and provide a better answers that gets the bounty or you might get another another few upvotes and get automatically awarded half the bounty.

Comment: Yep, that in fact was it. Thanks for advise and info regarding the policy. Will chill and wait.

Comment: @DaniDev to be fair, giving the bounty so quickly might defeat its purpose too. Bounties show up in order of how much time they have left, so with 5 days left, the OP might believe they will benefit from extra time as their question moves to the top page of 'featured'. Don't fret though. The extra visibility on their question also means extra eyes on your answer, which may net you some upvotes.